# c++11 decltype and infinite recursion in template loop

Tags: templates, c++11, recursion, type-traits, decltype

Consider the following code:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/def9fc0daddcca9f

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

struct A{
  char* ka;
};

struct B{
  char* baa;
};

template<typename T0, typename T1>
struct my_pair{
    my_pair(T0 el0, T1 el1): el0(el0), el1(el1) {}
    T0 el0;
    T1 el1; // may be next pair
};

template<typename T, int i, int current = 0>
auto constexpr get_my(const T& t, typename std::enable_if< i==current >::type* = 0) -> decltype(t.el0)
{
    return t.el0;
}

template<typename T, int i, int current = 0>
auto constexpr get_my(const T& t, typename std::enable_if< i!=current >::type* = 0) ->
    decltype( get_my<T, i, current+1>(t.el1) )
{
    return get_my<T, i, current+1>(t.el1);
}


int main()
{
    my_pair<int, my_pair<B,double>> p1(12.789, {B(), 3.14} );

    auto el1 = get_my<decltype(p1), 1>(p1);
    int t =1;
}
```

Here, I try to get n-th element of "array" (something like variadic sequence from boost fusion). 
When I compile it, compiler says:

```
error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use -ftemplate-depth= to increase the maximum) substituting 'template<class T, int i, int current> constexpr decltype (get_my<T, i, (current + 1)>(t.el1)) get_my(const T&, typename std::enable_if<(i != current)>::type*) [with T = my_pair<int, my_pair<B, double> >; int i = 1; int current = 900]'
     decltype( get_my<T, i, current+1>(t.el1) )
```

Why it not calls overloaded get_my, when i==current?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<typename T, int i, int current = 0>
auto constexpr get_my(const T& t, typename std::enable_if< i!=current >::type* = 0) ->
  decltype( get_my<T, i, current+1>(t.el1) )
{
  return get_my<T, i, current+1>(t.el1);
}
```

calls the nested `get_my` function with wrong arguments. The type for the nested call should be `get_my<decltype(t.el1), i, current+1>(t.el1)` instead of `get_my<T, i, current+1>(t.el1)`.

So the correct code should be:

```
template<typename T, int i, int current = 0>
auto constexpr get_my(const T& t, typename std::enable_if< i!=current >::type* = 0) ->
  decltype( get_my<decltype(t.el1), i, current+1>(t.el1) )
{
  return get_my<decltype(t.el1), i, current+1>(t.el1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Place deduced `template` arguments last.  If you also need default arguments you sometimes want to specify, consider a different overload with forwarding.

```
template<int i, typename T>
auto constexpr get_my // implementation with current=0
template<int i, int current, typename T>
auto constexpr get_my
```

and stop mentioning them explicitly, and your code gets simpler and your bug goes away.

(you used the wrong type explictly)

[live example](http://ideone.com/4anF3Y)

Comment: I don't get it. Could you, please, explain a little further? You mean, this allow to remove this decltype(t.el1) in  return get_my<decltype(t.el1), i, current+1>(t.el1); ?

Comment: @tower120 yes.  Remove the first type argument, everywhere, and let it be deduced.

Comment: `template T`: here is an error. And how could a non-default template parameter follow a default one?

Comment: @Constructor fixed the mistake.  Live example demonstrates it compiling.

Comment: There is `typename T` in your live example. And what about default template parameters which are followed by non-default ones?

Comment: As demonstrated [here](http://ideone.com/iI3hp5) you can have deduced arguments after a defaulted one.  Thanks for noticing my `template T` typo, I missed that one even on revision.

Comment: Yes, I have reread the standard and found nothing about this prohibition for function templates. But it is strange that you can have a non-default *and* non-deduced parameter after a defaulted one. In such case you should never use a default value of a template parameter as I can see. It is silly enough, I think.